# @ModelAttribute field becomes null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I have a spring boot application where I can registration, login etc. I want to make a "forgot password" feature. My user model includes a password what has some annotation (@NotBlank, @Size (min = 8)). When I register these annotations are working fine and I can't registrate in case I leave the password input fields blank or too short, I want these annotation to work at my "change password" method aswell.

```
public class User {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "{registration.usernameNotBlank}")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 32, message = "{registration.usernameSize}")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "{registration.passwordNotBlank}")
    @Size(min = 8, message = "{registration.passwordSize}")
    private String password;
}
```

In the following code snippet I check if the Confirmation Token the user got in email is valid and exists, in case it does I add the User object to my thymeleaf so it can hold on the page where I ask for new password:

```
    @GetMapping(PATH_CONFIRM_RESET)
    public String formForNewPasswordPage(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            @RequestParam(name = "token", required = true) String confirmationToken) {

        if (userService.getConfirmationToken(confirmationToken) != null) {              
            User user = userService.getUserByConfirmationToken(confirmationToken);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("user", user);
            return "redirect:/user/set-new-password";
        }

        return "redirect:/something-went-wrong";
    }
```

It works fine, it adds the the flashAttribute to the model and goes the next method:

```
    @GetMapping(PATH_SET_NEW_PASSWORD)
    public String changePasswordForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        System.out.println(user.toString());
        return "relatedToUserAccounts/change-password";
    }
```

On console:

```
 User [id=4, username=testuser, password=$2a$10$j.ZnbCtk.S.2LOUjXjrvh.NPWCvVzYaFQeMM.SQxZDnktI2.N5UCK, matchingPassword=null, email=testuser@gmail.com]
```

Here it gets the User object fine, the "System.out.println(user.toString());" shows that the object has all the data. It opens the next html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> 


<body>
    <section class="form">
        <form th:action="@{/user/set-new-password}" method="post" th:object="${user}">                

            <label th:text="#{changePassword.newPassword}">New password</label><br/>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" th:placeholder="#{password}" th:field="*{password}" autofocus/><br/>
            <input type="password" name="matchesPassword" placeholder="Password" th:placeholder="#{password}" th:field="*{matchingPassword}" /><br/>

            <input type="submit" class="submit-button" th:value="#{changePassword.submitButton}"/>
        </form>
    </section>
</body>
```

And the next method is being called if the user hit the submit button on this html:

```
@PostMapping(PATH_SET_NEW_PASSWORD)
    public String changePasswordOfUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {
        loggerInfoIsCalled(PATH_SET_NEW_PASSWORD, request);
        System.out.println(user.toString());
        return "redirect:/user/login";
    }
```

On console:

```
User [id=null, username=null, password=testuser, matchingPassword=testuser, email=null]
```

The problem happens here: the User object does not have the correct "username" and "email" fields anymore. Both is "null" while it has the new password and new matchingPassword.

With example: The "changePasswordForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user)" System.out.println() put this on my console:

```
User [id=4, username=testuser, password=$2a$10$j.ZnbCtk.S.2LOUjXjrvh.NPWCvVzYaFQeMM.SQxZDnktI2.N5UCK, matchingPassword=null, email=testuser@gmail.com]
```

I got the HTML page where I can give the new password, click on the button and the User object looks like this now:

```
User [id=null, username=null, password=testuser, matchingPassword=testuser, email=null]
```

id, username, email became null.

I would prefer to not make a method that checks all the contraints I put in the User model (call a method on new passwords to check it's not blank or too short...)

Comment: The model is destroyed after/while rendering the page. The model isn't persistent. I you don't put the fields inside the form they are gone. However should you really use the `User` entity for changing the password or create a specific form containing the username (or id) together with both passwords. The `matchesPassword` isn't really a field of the `User` but only there to support a certain use case.